# Laravel authentication with Pin (secondary password)

Tags: authentication, laravel, passwords

When user wants to login, they are prompted with `username` and `password`.
I want to add new layer of security, by prompting user to enter their `pin`.
So after the user entered their `username` and `password`, they will need to enter their `pin` to successfully log in.

Can I achieve this with Laravel's built-in `Auth` class ?
Or do I have to use third party libraries such as [Confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) or [Sentry](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps. I am not certain about whether you can do it with built-in auth. But if you want to customize your layer of auth, just create a validator or simply add a filter which includes pin validation. This should do.